# Why am I getting the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure", error when trying to implment Gmail Oauth

Tags: html, web, gmail-api

### Errors

```
Cookie “G_AUTHUSER_H” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite cb=gapi.loaded_0:159:401

Cookie “G_AUTHUSER_H” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite cb=gapi.loaded_0:159:401
```

Cookie “G_ENABLED_IDPS” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite cb=gapi.loaded_0:273:21

### Problem

---

So I've been trying to use the Gmail Oauth API to set up logins into my website. It was working fine on my localhost just of XAMPP but once one of my team members tried to move the website off of XAMPP onto a Node Js server. It would refresh constantly if you logged in using your gmail.

Without the gmail Oauth the website seems to work fine it is just when I try use it.

Comment: Can you explain what "refresh constantly" means? In what part of the process does it occur? The OAuth completes successfully?

Comment: Let us know if you have any fix for that I am using Hugo Static Site Generator. Facing same issue.

Comment: Facing same problem, site just stays on login page, interestingly this started happening only on firefox, that too after we upgrade node + react(and general package upgrade), so far no clue whats causing logins to fail, we only see these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem with the google refreshing the page by only loading the logIn function if I was on the logIn page. Otherwise, it was just running the function over and over again on other pages.

Maybe not the best solution but this is what I did.

```
        //loads if page is login.html
        switch (current) {
            case "http://localhost:2000/login.html":
                window.location.href = "./index.html"
                console.log("Note on page");
                break;
        }
```